# lwip stack netconn api keep connection "keep-alive"

Tags: c, lwip

I'm currently working with the lwip stack to implement a modbus server, but the "keep-alive" function doesn't work. Can someone look to my problem?

code:

```
static void prvweb_ParseHTMLRequest( struct netconn *pxNetCon )
{
struct netbuf *pxRxBuffer;
portCHAR *pcRxString;
unsigned portSHORT usLength;
static unsigned portLONG ulPageHits = 0;

    while(netconn_recv( pxNetCon, &pxRxBuffer) != ERR_OK)
    {
        vTaskDelay( webSHORT_DELAY );
    }
    if( pxRxBuffer != NULL )
    {
        /* Where is the data? */
        netbuf_data( pxRxBuffer, ( void * ) &pcRxString, &usLength );

        if(( NULL != pcRxString               )
        && ( !strncmp( pcRxString, "GET", 3 ) ))
        {
            /********************************* 
                    Generate HTML page 
            *********************************/

            /* Write out the dynamically generated page. */
            netconn_write( pxNetCon, cDynamicPage, (u16_t) strlen( cDynamicPage ), NETCONN_COPY );
        }
        netbuf_delete( pxRxBuffer );
    }

    netconn_close( pxNetCon );
    netconn_delete( pxNetCon );
}
```

I changed the following settings:

```
#ifndef LWIP_TCP_KEEPALIVE
#define LWIP_TCP_KEEPALIVE              1
#endif



#ifndef  TCP_KEEPIDLE_DEFAULT
#define  TCP_KEEPIDLE_DEFAULT     7200000UL /* Default KEEPALIVE timer in milliseconds */
#endif

#ifndef  TCP_KEEPINTVL_DEFAULT
#define  TCP_KEEPINTVL_DEFAULT    75000UL   /* Default Time between KEEPALIVE probes in milliseconds */
#endif

#ifndef  TCP_KEEPCNT_DEFAULT
#define  TCP_KEEPCNT_DEFAULT      9U        /* Default Counter for KEEPALIVE probes */
#endif
```

Are there other things I must do in my code? If i tried this the server will end the connection after transmit the HTML page. I tried to delete  netconn_close( pxNetCon ); and/or netconn_delete( pxNetCon ); ,but this will not give the right solution. The connection will stay open, but I cannot connect again.

So are there other settings I didn't use? Or are there modification in the code needed?

Comment: By keep-alives, do you mean [HTTP persistent connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)?

Comment: Hi, No I mean the keep-alive functionality of the TCP protocol. The example is a http protocol, but i'm trying to implement a modbus server with keep-alive funtionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LWIP_TCP_KEEPALIVE controls compiling in support for TCP keepalives and by default each connection has keepalives off.

The above application is using the netconn API for managing it's connection and there is no netconn API to enable the SO_KEEPALIVE option.  In order to do this, you'll need to be using LwIP's BSD-like sockets API and the setsockopt() call:

`int optval = 1;
 setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, sizeof(optval));`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response! That explains a lot! In that case i'm going to use the BSD-like socket API! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, I was thinking about it and I have one question. The BSD socket API is build on top of the Netconn api, so how is it possible that the BSD socket has this feature and the Netconn API doesn't. use it the raw api to to this?

Comment: There are some operations that the sockets API performs that operate directly on the PCB (protocol control block) which is a level lower than netconn.  If you look at the [sockets.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/lwip.git/tree/src/api/sockets.c) around line 2080, we can see that SO_KEEPALIVE ends up calling ip_set_option() to enable the keep alive option

Answer (score 1):

How to enable Keep-Alive when Raw API

1. in lwipopts.h

```
#define LWIP_TCP_KEEPALIVE  1 // enable "kepp-alive"
#define TCP_KEEPIDLE_DEFAULT    1000 // keep_idle : dont' send keep-alive until keep_idle after connecting
#define TCP_KEEPCNT_DEFAULT     9U // keep_cnt : increase when no response after sending keep-alive every keep_intvl
```

2. when call tcp_connect(pcb, ...)

```
pcb->keep_intvl = 1000; // send "keep-alive" every 1000ms
```

3. in loop()...

```
if(pcb_client->keep_cnt==pcb_client->keep_cnt_sent)
{
    tcp_client_connection_close(pcb_client, client_s);
}
```

this settings make timeout 10s after server unplugged